# Apache server with cgi and bash back end issue

Tags: apache, bash, cgi, signals

The server writes dynamic files while the webpage is executed. And cleans the files at the end of execution.

Normal scenario:

```
  I. Load page
 II. cgi calls bash script to do some backend stuff (takes a few 
     seconds, creates some tmp files)
III. bash script returns, and cgi removes the files at the end of execution
```

Exceptional scenario:

```
  I. Load page
 II. cgi calls bash script to do some backend stuff (takes a few 
     seconds, creates some tmp files)
III. user clicks stop on browser, and the perl script terminates
 IV. tmp files left on server :(
```

I am sure there is a way to detect the signal from the browser (hence handle the exception), but as I am a web development noob, I don't know what to search for...

Comment: I know cgi is old school technique, but I guess any recommendation will help as I will try to look for what to search as well

Comment: If the perl script dies prematurely, it's because it has received a signal. Have you tried trapping sigterm or sigpipe?

Comment: @thatotherguy Hey, thanks for you answer, I had a look at the doc at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), but got confused... Could you explain the investigation a bit nore?

Comment: Create signal handlers for sigterm and sigpipe, have them e.g. create a file `/tmp/handler_executed`, and verify that they work correctly if you run the script from a shell and `kill -TERM yourpid`. Once it works, run it from the browser, hit stop, and see if the file is created.